# How can I ensure a button is visible when the keyboard is used?

Tags: flutter

I have a form with some elements and a button on the bottom. If I click inside a input the keyboard appears and covers the button. I want the page scrolls down so the button should be visible. I tried to use WidgetsBinding to find out when the keyoard is shown and `controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);` to scroll to the end of the ListView but that doesn't work.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  Size lastSize;
  Menu selected = Menu.Email;
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @protected
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    lastSize = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body:
      Container(
        height: height,
        width: width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [AppColors.primaryLight, AppColors.primary],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
        ),
        child: ListView(
            controller: controller,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, bottom: 35),
                child: Align(
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/images/logo.svg',
                    height: width / 3,
                    width: width / 3,
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                )),
            Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.white), bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                selected = Menu.Email;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'Email',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: selected == Menu.Email ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ))),
                    Expanded(
                        child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                selected = Menu.Phone;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'Phone',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: selected == Menu.Phone ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ))),
                  ],
                )),
            LoginWithEmail()

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information, perhaps a code sample showing your current state, and illustrating how it's not meeting your expectation?

Comment: Why not just use 
Column => Expanded => ListView(your data) //new line
             => GestureDetector/FlatButton (your Button) //new line
             => LoginWithEmail()

this way you can omit the process of going to bottom part of the ListView and stick your button

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the package [keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility#-readme-tab-) to trigger your scroll controller.

```dart
_scrollDown(bool visible) {
   if (visible)
      controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
}

@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(onChange: _scrollDown);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a SingleChildScrollView widget to enable scrolling when the keyboard appears.

```
 return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Scaffold(
     body: Container(...)));
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't scroll to the bottom. In this example, it scrolls down so the first button is visible but not the other buttons: https://dev.to/rubensdemelo/flutter-forms-improving-uiux-with-singlechildscrollview-36gd